# Differences between the APK permissions in system vs product partitions

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-source

Per the document here:

https://source.android.com/devices/bootloader/product-partitions

Google says:

> **The /product partition in Android 9 is an extension of the /system partition**. As there is weak ABI between /product and /system partitions, both must be upgraded at the same time and the ABI should be System SDK-based. If the System SDK doesn't cover all API surfaces between /product and /system, it is up to the OEM to maintain their own ABI between the two partitions.
>
> The /product and /system partitions can have dependency on each other. However, tests with the Generic System Image (GSI) must work properly without the /product partition.
>
> The /product partition must not have any dependency on /vendor partition and no direct interaction between the /product partition and the /vendor is permitted (enforced by SEpolicy).

I'm having difficulties with an APK that is not behaving the same when placed in /product/priv-app vs /system/priv-app.

APK details:

- signed with platform key
- runs as system (system shared uid in manifest)
- communicates with sockets (owned by system) on /data

AOSP:

- multiuser enabled

The problem:

When the APK is placed in (manually, as in simply dropped in the folder) /system/priv-app all functionality is correct. The app is able to communicate through a socket placed in /data. The socket is owned by system and the app (in a multiuser environment) has 2 instances. One that runs as system and one that runs as user. When something happens this app writes to the socket. While on /system/priv-app the app is able to connect to the socket and carry out write successfully. When I generate a new clean system image and drop the apk in /product/priv-app instead then I get a permission denied on the socket.

The docs are very confusing and for years Google has yet to clarify or list specific permissions based on placement of APKs on the system.

I've read things like some apps are more system than others but what does that mean. So all I know about the permissions is from my own experiments.

This behavior is not described in any document and I would like someone else who has dealt with priv-apps in product partition to chime in on this and clarify if possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Is it resolved? If yes, please share your answer.
I think once we move the app to the product partition, it no more refers to the signature and permission in the system partition. We shall have it in the /product partition. Also, there are limitations in accessing APIs/members from the product partition.

Comment: @Arnold Balliu did you find the solution?